# jqplot Highlighter for different line graphs

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, graph, jqplot

I have a series of line graphs in a `jqPlot` chart. What I want to do is turn off highlighting for all the graphs except one graph for which I want the Highlighting to happen. How can i do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't have a good example of how to do this yet or time to cook one up, but I'll update when I do.  In all events, the highlighter plugin adds a showHighlight option to each series.  If you set `showHighlight = false` for a given series, no highlight should appear.