# jqplot show highlighter on only one chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, jqplot, jqplot-highlighter

I have a jqplot chart with two data lines. Only one should have the highlighter enabled.
I tried this:

```
series:[
    {
        highlighter: {
            formatString: "",
            show: false
        }
    },
    {
        highlighter: {
            formatString: "Day %s: %d",
            show: true
        }
    }
]
```

But unfortunately, this doesn't work: the highlighter shows a small empty dot at the first line, whereas it should show nothing.

How do I show the highlighter on one chart and not on the other?

Comment: You might want to check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003772/jqplot-highlighter-for-different-line-graphs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very interesting question (+1).
The only solution that came to my mind, as playing with options of a plot didn't help, was to clean the canvas and hide highlighter's tooltip every time that it is suppose to show. This is done in the code below and [presented in a working sample available here](http://jsfiddle.net/Boro/LSLzB/).

```
$('#chart').bind('jqplotMouseMove', function(event, xy, axesData, neighbor, plot) {
    if (neighbor && neighbor.seriesIndex == 0) {
        var drawingCanvas = $(".jqplot-highlight-canvas")[0];
        var context = drawingCanvas.getContext('2d');
        context.clearRect(0, 0, drawingCanvas.width, drawingCanvas.height);
        $('.jqplot-highlighter-tooltip').hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks for your reply! I guess I have to change the value 0 in the if-sentence in case I want to hide another series?

Comment: Yes that is what you should do or add a list and a for loop and you will have it for many series.

Answer (score 2):

set `showHighlight: false` for the series for which you don't need highlighter